# Wamp on Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, wamp, wampserver

For a school project, I need to install a server with Wamp but I need to have access everywhere so maybe is it possible to install it on my Raspberry. So is it possible and if is it how ?
Thanks you so much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) is windows only and I do not think the Pi can run Windows (maybe Windows RT, but WAMP is compiled for X86 not ARM).  It can run a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) stack and installation depends on your distribution.  For Raspbian it would be something along the lines of (typed in the terminal):

```
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install mysql-server
mysql_secure_installation
apt-get install php5 php-pear php5-mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to install windows on a raspberry pi which I don't think would work to well.

You could just use Lamp, Linux, and SSH to access it anywhere which is basically the same thing.